# Reverse array of lines read from file in CGI Script

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a Perl script I wrote, saved it as `index.cgi`, and it reads in a table of shortlinks and their expansion from a TSV:

redirects.tsv:

```
$ head redirects.tsv
about   http://tobilehman.com/about
gapminder   http://www.gapminder.org/
speed   http://speedof.me/
delete  http://justdelete.me/
terms   http://tosdr.org/
re  https://www.debuggex.com/
1   http://www.diffen.com/difference/Diffen_vs_Wikipedia
2   http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/10/google-fiber-now-explicitly-permits-home-servers/
3   https://www.senate.gov/legislative/LIS/roll_call_lists/roll_call_vote_cfm.cfm?congress=113
ifs http://tobilehman.com/blog/2013/10/19/revisiting-spaces-in-file-names/
```

index.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
my $current_time = time();

my $file = "redirects.tsv";

open my $lines, $file or die "Could not open redirects.tsv";

my $redirect_html = "";

while ( my $line = <$lines> ) {
    $line =~ /^([0-9a-z_-]+)\t(.*)/;
    #$redirect_html = "$redirect_html\n<li><a href='$1'>tblh.mn/$1</a> ($2)</li>";
    my $link = "http://tblh.mn/$1";
    $redirect_html
        = "$redirect_html<tr><td><a href='$link'>$link</td><td>&rarr;</td><td style='padding-left:15px'>$2</td></tr>\n";
}

print <<HTML;
<html>
<head>
  <link href="/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <title>tblh.mn &rarr; tobilehman.com</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Current Time: $current_time</h1>
  <h1>Short Links</h1>
  <table>
        $redirect_html
  </table>
</body>
</html>

HTML
exit;
```

Right now, the links are being printed as in Last-In-Last-Out, but I'd like them to be printed as Last-In-First-Out.

I tried solving this by using `reverse(<$lines>)` and `<reverse($lines)>`, neither of which worked. I am not very familiar with Perl, so forgive me if this is a noob problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for my $line (reverse(<$lines>)) {
   ...
}
```

Alternatively, [File::ReadBackwards](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::ReadBackwards).

Answer (score 2):

As has already been pointed out, you can use [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) to reverse an array, or [`File::ReadBackwards`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::ReadBackwards) to do what its name implies.

Additionally, I would like to encourage you to do some basic error checking in your script:

1. Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY script.
2. Include [`use autodie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) any time you're doing file processing.
3. Make sure that your regular expression matched before using the capture variables.

And stylistically:

1. Use the concatenation operator to build a string `$string .= "more string";`
2. Use alternative delimiters like `qq{ }` whenever you want to include double quotes in a string.

Including these changes with a couple other small fixes:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

my $current_time = time();

my $file = "redirects.tsv";

open my $fh, '<', $file;

my $redirect_html = "";

for ( reverse <$fh> ) {
    chomp;
    if ( my ( $shortlink, $full ) = /^([0-9a-z_-]+)\t(.*)/ ) {
        my $link = "http://tblh.mn/$shortlink";
        $redirect_html
            .= qq{<tr><td><a href="$link">$link</td><td>&rarr;</td><td style="padding-left:15px">$full</td></tr>\n};
        #$redirect_html .= "\n<li><a href='$1'>tblh.mn/$1</a> ($2)</li>";
    }
}

print <<"HTML";
<html>  
<head>
  <link href="/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <title>tblh.mn &rarr; tobilehman.com</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Current Time: $current_time</h1>
  <h1>Short Links</h1>
  <table>
        $redirect_html
  </table>
</body>
</html>

HTML
exit;
```

Comment: On the stylistic point, why is concatenation preferred over interpolation?

Comment: Simplicity.  Your intent is immediately visible by seeing the concatenation operator `.=`.  It's obvious that you're building a string, and so one immediately looks up to ensure that the `my` declaration is outside the loop.

Comment: That's debatable, having a single line that shows the whole string is simpler, in my opinion. It doesn't take long to see the $ signs in there and see what is variable and what isn't.

Comment: You can have your own preferences, of course.  However, two other benefits.  1)  It saves typing.  1 character vs 14 in this case.  2) It's not uncommon to change an implementation method from building an output string to just a straight `print`.  With the simpler format one can just remove the beginning and substitute it with print.  With the latter, one has to recognize that there is a variable inside the string that needs to be removed too.  This isn't major, and obviously can be worked around.  However, why not just go with simpler since it saves time both now and perhaps future too?